# When should i use `==` vs `===` vs `isequal`

Tags: julia

I see that julia has 3 different ways
to do equality.

`==`, `===`, and `isequal`

Which should I use, and when?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601141/what-is-the-difference-between-and-comparison-operators-in-julia

Comment: Once check it Same is explained Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601141/what-is-the-difference-between-and-comparison-operators-in-julia

Answer (score 13):

#### `===` is the  built-in equality.

- On primitives, it is value equality: if they have the same bit level representation then they are equal.
- On mutable structs, it is referential equality: things are equal if they are the same memory locations.
- On immutable structs, it is structural equality: two structures are equal if they are of the same type and all their fields are equal.

In all 3 cases this is all more or less just bit-level equality, references to memory are pointers.
(But of fancyness to make the immutable struct version recursive)

Ideally, one wouldn't use this much, because it is not customizable.
Sometimes though it is good to use because the optimizer can reason about it really well, so it can lead to better performance for hot loops.

#### `==` is general purpose equality

It is overloadable.
For Floats it follows the IEEE rules,  i.e. `-0.0 == 0.0`, `NaN != NaN`.
And it follows 3 values logic rules for `missing == missing` resulting in `missing`.

if `==` is not defined then it falls back to `===`

If you have defined `==`, you need to define `hash` as `isequal` falls back to using `==`, see below.

#### `isequal` is equality for purpose of dictionaries.

I don't know a much better way to put it.
Things that are `isequal` are considered the same for purposes of `Dict` and `Set`.
So you can't have two items that are `isequal` as distinct keys in a `Dict`.

Use this if you want to be sure that `NaN`s are equal to each other,
and similarly that missings are equal to each other.

When defining `isequal` you also must define `hash`. 
`isequal(a, b)` implies `hash(a) == hash(b)`

If `isequal` is not defined, then it falls back to `==`

Comment: I don't understand why the distinction between mutable and immutable structs. Why would it be true if two immutable struct instances have different memory addresses but the same values of the fields when they are distinguishable for living in different places in memory?

Answer (score 7):

Basically:

- `==` when you are interested in the values of two objects: `1 == 1`->`true` and `1 == 1.0`->`true`
- `===` when you want to make sure that two objects cannot be distinguished (including arrays pointing to different memory): `1 === 1`->`true` but `1 === 1.0`->`false` and `A = [1, 2, 3]; B = [1, 2, 3]` leads to `A == B`->`true` but `A === B`->`false` (`A === A`->`true`).
- `isequal()` same as `==` but handles floating point numbers differently: `NaN == NaN`->`false` but `isequal(NaN, NaN)`->`true`.

A deeper discussion [here](https://riptutorial.com/julia-lang/example/25048/using----------and-isequal).